# Views integration broken

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

Since the last two updates I am having severe issues with the views integration with Drupal. The views module hasn't changed, but it doesn't seem to work after the 4.74 and 4.76 updates.

When upgrading to 4.74 I lost all the custom fields in the integration and now with the 4.76 I lost even more fields like event names, dates and contact fields.

Does anyone else have this issue and knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried clearing all Drupal caches then running update.php for Drupal? This fixes views for me

Comment: Thank you... that seems to fix the issue I had with the last update. However I still have the issue with the custom fields.

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'civicrm_contact.custom_7' in 'where clause'

I still have this issue and the column indeed does not exist.

Comment: if you are using civicrm entity module you often get Fields showing in Views - those are the ones that have 'no help' or somesuch message in your Field selector - avoid those ones.

Comment: The Entity module seems to indeed be the problem. I disabled the entity module and the fields show up fine now.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed civicrm_entity_views_extras and therefore both entity and  civicrm_entity, so disabling is not an option. My civicrm views break as soon as I migrate from production to stage. Clearing all drupal cache (which includes views) is not helping me. The only thing that seems to help is

- Access the failing view
- Specifically clear the views cache (drush cc views)

Apparently it should fail once and only then after cache cleared again, the cache is finally build properly. I will try now to deactivate views cache before migrating to see if that helps.

Comment: The best solution imho is to simple disable views data cache in advanced views settings. I did not notice any speed gain in my situation and reports are not accessed by all and not daily.